# Most efficient way to exclude indexed rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new to Python & pandas and am struggling with (hierachical) indexes. I've got the basics covered, but am lost with more advanced slicing and cross-sectioning.

For example, with the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3)),
    index=pd.Index(['Ohio', 'Colorado', 'New York'], name='state'), columns=pd.Index(['one', 'two', 'three'], name='number'))
```

I want to select everything except the row with index 'Colorado'. For a small dataset I could do:

```
data.ix[['Ohio','New York']]
```

But if the number of unique index values is large, that's impractical. Naively, I would expect a syntax like

```
data.ix[['state' != 'Colorado']]
```

However, this only returns the first record 'Ohio' and doesn't return 'New York'. This works, but is cumbersome

```
filter = list(set(data.index.get_level_values(0).unique()) - set(['Colorado']))
data[filter]
```

Surely there's a more Pythonic, verbose way of doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a Python issue, not a `pandas` one: `'state' != 'Colorado'` is True, so what `pandas` gets is `data.ix[[True]]`.

You could do

```
>>> data.loc[data.index != "Colorado"]
number    one  two  three
state                    
Ohio        0    1      2
New York    6    7      8

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

or use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
>>> data.query("state != 'New York'")
number    one  two  three
state                    
Ohio        0    1      2
Colorado    3    4      5

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

if you don't like the duplication of `data`.  (Quoting the expression passed to the `.query()` method is one of the only ways around the fact that otherwise Python would evaluate the comparison before `pandas` ever saw it.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a robust solution that will also work with MultiIndex objects

## Single Index

```
excluded = ['Ohio']
indices = data.index.get_level_values('state').difference(excluded)
indx = pd.IndexSlice[indices.values]
```

The output

```
In [77]: data.loc[indx]
Out[77]:
number    one  two  three
state
Colorado    3    4      5
New York    6    7      8
```

## MultiIndex Extension

Here I extend to a MultiIndex example...

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(18).reshape(6,3), index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[u'AU', u'UK'], [u'Derby', u'Kensington', u'Newcastle', u'Sydney']], labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]], names=[u'country', u'town']), columns=pd.Index(['one', 'two', 'three'], name='number'))
```

Assume we want to exclude `'Newcastle'` from both examples in this new MultiIndex

```
excluded = ['Newcastle']
indices = data.index.get_level_values('town').difference(excluded)
indx = pd.IndexSlice[:, indices.values]
```

Which gives the expected result

```
In [115]: data.loc[indx, :]
Out[115]:
number              one  two  three
country town
AU      Derby         0    1      2
        Sydney        3    4      5
UK      Derby         0    1      2
        Kensington    3    4      5
```

## Common Pitfalls

1. Make sure that all levels of your index are sorted, you require `data.sort_index(inplace=True)`
2. Make sure you include the null slice for columns `data.loc[indx, :]`
3. Sometimes `indx = pd.IndexSlice[:, indices]` is enough but I found that often I needed to use `indx = pd.IndexSlice[:, indices.values]`